# How to import Python Libraries

Tags: python, jython

I'm new to python and I'm using jython to create classes from python files.
I have jython and python both configured in my environment variables and when I type either in the command prompt I get their respective versions.
That's right I'm using windows :(

I need to create json output and was able to finally get the 'import json' to work and not give me an ImportError: No module name json.
Now I would like to import pysftp but I'm getting ImportError: No module named pysftp.  Same thing with Paramiko import.

With that said I updated my jython to 2.7 and python version to 2.7.9 so I can use pip to import those libraries.  Is this really what pip is for?  How do I import library pysftp into my py file without it giving me the ImportError?

I'm a Java guy so I tried to locate pysftp jar and add it to the python Lib folder but that didn't work.

How do I import python libraries?

Comment: Do you use ubuntu? Try removing pysftp first and then do this:

`sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev`

then reinstall pysftp and see if you still encounter the same issues. Maybe it is a matter that the dependencies are not right.

Comment: I'm on a windows machine.  I will try to mimic your response in my environment.  Thanks

Comment: Could you attach the exact errors (traceback) you are getting when doing `import json` or `import pysftp`

Comment: Tried to install pysftp-0.2.9 into jython-2.7.1.  First with pip, then by downloading the .tar.gz file and invoking setup.py directly.  No luck.  There is definitely something wrong.